# how to filter an array of array using underscore javascript

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

I have an array of object as below:

```
[{name:'Initiative 1', actionList:[{name:'action 1', productionLine:'436767'}]}, {name:'Initiative 2', actionList:[{name:'action 2', productionLine:'892128'}]}]
```

And I would like to filter the results based on some property of actionList element for ex based on productionLine value.

This is my code which doesnt work as expected, I get an empty result.

```
initiatives.forEach(function(initiative) {
     var newArr = _.filter(initiative.actionList, function({
         return o.productionLine == selectedProductionLine;
     });
     initiative.actionList = newArr;
});
```

Expected:
Input given: 892128
Result:

```
[{name:'Initiative 1', actionList:[]}, {name:'Initiative 2', actionList:[{name:'action 2', productionLine:'892128'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks off on your filter:

`var newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])`

Check out [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The snippet below should give you what you need.

```js
let initiatives = [{
  name: 'Initiative 1',
  actionList: [{
    name: 'action 1',
    productionLine: '436767'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Initiative 2',
  actionList: [{
    name: 'action 2',
    productionLine: '892128'
  }]
}]

let selectedProductionLine = '892128';

initiatives.forEach(function(initiative) {
  newArray = initiative.actionList.filter(function(actionList) {
    return actionList.productionLine == selectedProductionLine;
  });
  initiative.actionList = newArray
});

console.log(initiatives);
```